# mySQL Fails When executed from PHP without Error Message

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to execute an SQL Statement but it fails without producing an error message. Please can you let me know what is going wrong?

I'm using the same database connection that I've used successfully in other pages for SELECT, and INSERT statements. I've tested the SQL statement successfully in phpMyAdmin. But when executed from php it fails without error message, all other statement in the site work fine.

Database connection include

```
<?php
$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>



// Connect to DB
include 'incDBConnection.php';
$SQL = "SELECT * from tbl_Properties";

echo "<br/> <br />";
if ($conn->query($SQL) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "<br/> <br />Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Is display_errors on and error_reporting set to show errors in your php.ini?

Comment: A select query doesn't return true. It returns an object, or false on failure. So type/strict comparison with a boolean true will *always* fail.

Comment: @Yury yes show errors is on, this is the only occasion where no errors are reported after a failed execution

Comment: @Qirel I have the same issue with this statement `"UPDATE tbl_Properties SET pty_Rent=500, pty_RentFrequency='Weekly', pty_Deposit=600 WHERE pty_ID=35"` the select statement is used to remove any compliactions

Comment: @Qirel I changed the query back to the update statement and it work, thanks this answered the question.